# how to stop flutter engine

Tags: android, flutter

i want to stop flutter engine in Android

There is 2 flutter engine exist (D/FlutterGeolocator( 5406): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 2) and i want to stop both engine

so i use this code

```
await stopForegroundService();
      await SystemNavigator.pop();
      exit(0);
```

first it seems like engine is stopped but soon "There is still another flutter engine connected, not stopping location service" message appear and then application is restarted

1.
`exit(0);`
2.
`stopForegroundService();`
3.
`SystemNavigator.pop();`

4. combination of above 1~3 also i have using async await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here's code for terminating the Flutter engine on Android and iOS

---

### Android (JAVA)

```
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

public class MyActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private FlutterEngine engine;

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (engine != null) {
            engine.destroy();
            engine = null;
        }
    }
}
```

### IOS (Object C)

```
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

@interface MyViewController : FlutterViewController
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.engine destroyContext];
}

@end
```